# How to bulk and set null parameters by default using elasticsearch-py?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulk

I'm currently trying to bulk data using the following code

```
for i, entry in enumerate(result):
    aux = encode(entry)
    body.append({
        "_index": "laborum_profiles",
        "_type": "profile",
        "_id": aux["id"],
        "_source": {
            "@timestamp": datetime.now(),
            "@version": "1",
            "address": aux["location"] if "location" in aux else "",
            # Here I'm using a function to calculate the age
            "age": age_calculus(aux["birthDate"]) if "birthDate" in aux else 0,
            "birthday": aux["birthDate"] if "birthDate" in aux else None,
            "cellphone": aux["phones"] if "phones" in aux else [],
            "country": aux["nationality"] if "nationality" in aux else "",
            "creation_date": aux["createdAt"] if "createdAt" in aux else None,
        }
    })
helpers.bulk(es, body)
```

I wonder if this is a good practice, if not, what else could I try? 
I'm doing this because there is plenty of empty data in the database.

Comment: You can shorten that to `aux.get("location", "")`

Comment: Thanks sir, is this a good way to bulk data? If not, could you give me some documentation or an example?